# migration between different dbs using flyway

Tags: sql-server, amazon-redshift, database-migration, flyway, apache-phoenix

We have different DBs in the organization like MS SQL, Phoenix (HBase), Redshift. 
  Question: is it possible to migrate between different types of DB using tools like flyway or other. I mean in case we have Schema in MS SQL, what is the way to easily migrate to RedShift? In case schema has been changed, is it supported to maintain/upgrade schema for a different type of DB.

Thanks
Oleg.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating data to Redshift requires a different pattern, specific to redshift.

Your source database -> s3 csv (compressed) and split into chunks if very large

s3 data -> redshift staging

redshift staging -> target redshift tables

You might also consider whether CDC is applicable to your use case.

I have had good success recently with AWS DMS, it handles the above process transparently and automatically. it also works with CDC where applicable and supports many sources.

It will create the target tables automatically. You have the option to modify the target tables if you wish (manually).

MS SQL can be used as a source, but not sure how to use hbase as a source. you may have to export that manually to s3 first.

See https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

Comment: Thanks, Jon.
 I will take a look to DMS service. In our case, it is not just a migration DB's as is. It is an ETL process involved. Also, there is not the only redshift involved in the process. For HBase we are using Phoenix, it is SQL skin with JDBC driver, so the relational model is in place.

  The question is the same is there a way to migrate with schema versions between different DB. Example MS SQL and Phoenix. Phoenix and RedShift.

Thanks
Oleg.